# How to show only Notification's icon in the task bar (without Heads Up)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to show only notification icon ( without any Heads Up ). 
I thought it can be done by the code below, but when I execute this code, I've receive also a HeadsUp with `contentTitle` and `contentText`. I don't want it to be shown to user.

I've nulled the customHeadsUpContentView, but it still shows up.

```
String id = "my_channel_01";
CharSequence name = "someName";
String description = "even bigger name";
int importance = 0;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN;
}
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(application);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application, id);
}
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(application, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(application,
                0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.big_anchor)
        .setContentTitle("Status")
        .setContentText("ARMED")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(null) // ?
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(32345, mBuilder.build());
```

**--UPDATE--**

In other words, I want my notification to be shown without this:
[image]
**--UPDATE--**

What is interesting, this Heads Up is showing only on devices with API 26 (Oreo). My phone with Nougat everything works.

Comment: remove this lines .setContentTitle("Status")
        .setContentText("ARMED") and test

Comment: then why you set title and content text remove it and try

Comment: Still shows. Obviously thinner.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question correctly. I am happy when the user opens the taskbar and sees what is the status. The only think I am not happy about is that when I am adding this icon, the Heads Up shows for 5s. When it disappears everything is exactly as I want.

Comment: Are you able to solve this @Michał

Answer (score 0):

try this , may be it is useful

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.big_anchor)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(null) 
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5mRjc still shows. I want to remove this Heads Up. It clearly is something obvious ( people tend to ask question how to show it, instead how to **not** show it. )